# Try to convert all strings in argv[] to integers and store them into a new array

Tags: c

I'm new to C and I'm trying to convert all strings that the user typed in the command line to integers and store them into a new array, so that I can use it later. But I get a "segmentation fault (core dumped)" issue.

Can someone check with my code and point out the error(s)?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    long int conv[argc - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        conv[i] = strtol(argv[i + 1], NULL, 10);
    }
```

If I run this program like, `./main 1 2 3`, then `{1, 2, 3}` should be stored in the new array of integers.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments you pass in to your program are stored in `argv[1]` to `argv[argc-1]`, so you'd want to change the for loop to something like this: `for (int i = 1; ...) {...}`. Also, with `strtol(argv[i+1],NULL,10);`, when `i==argc-1`, you're trying to access the array out of bounds.

Here's a modified version of your code with the fixes applied:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    long int conv[argc-1];
    for(int i=1;i<argc;i++){
        conv[i-1]=strtol(argv[i],NULL,10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop attempts to access an "out-of-bounds" array element on its last iteration: if you run the program with, say, `./main 1 2 3`, then `argc` will be 4 and the last argument will be in `argv[3]`. However, when the loop index, `i` is 3, the loop will still run and you will be attempting to read `argv[i + i]` – which is `argv[4]` and thus beyond the end of the array.

You can simplify your loop (or, at least, rewrite it) to use the *actual* `i` value for the `argv` index and `i - 1` for the `conv` index; but, of course, you then need to start the loop with `i = 1`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    long int conv[argc - 1];
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        conv[i - 1] = strtol(argv[i], NULL, 10);
    }
    // Data check:
    for (int j = 0; j < argc - 1; ++j) {
        printf("Data %d is %ld\n", j, conv[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```